# Loop not handling '\n' comparison properly

Tags: c++, c++11, input, while-loop, comparison

I am trying to read from an input file with this general format:

```
1 2 3
2 1
3 1

1 3 4 5
3 1 2
2 3
4 1
5 1
```

To construct an adjacency list for a graph where the first number is the vertex number, and the ones after that are adjacent vertices. Graphs are separated from each other by a blank line. I made a function to get the next number in the sequence, which is written to stop when either a space or '\n' is being detected. However, the comparison of my nextChar to '\n' is not causing it to exit the loop, and the stoi() is throwing an std::invalid_argument, which I thought I had accounted for in my while loop. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, and I don't know how to fix my code to work the way I want it to.

```
*** CODE REDACTED ***
```

This is the third attempt at coding something to achieve this. I had already tried the >> stream extractor, but it was not working, since I have multiple graphs in each data file, separated by a blank line, and the stream extractor doesn't detect the blank line, which I need, so that I know to start a new graph.

Comment: This function seems to be trying to do pretty much what the stream extractor does.  Why not just use `input >> number;`?

Comment: Pete's solution seems easier. As to why the code doesn't work, could the input file have DOS file endings? that means it ends with "\r\n" instead of just "\n". It would be a better idea to have the condition be `while(nextChar is '1' or '2' or ... '9')` that way it would exit the loop even if there are annoying things in the file.

Comment: I tried using the >> stream extractor, and it wasn't working, since I have multiple graphs per data file separated by blank lines, I needed a way to detect a blank line, which I thought I could do by comparing a character to '\n'. That way, I would know when to end a graph and start the loop for the next graph input.

Comment: @HiryūShōtenHa *I tried using the >> stream extractor, and it wasn't working* -- If all else failed, you could simply read the entire line in at once using `getline` and parse the data yourself or use `std::istringstream` and `>>` to do the parsing for you.  I'm surprised that wasn't the first thing you would try to do, instead of this sketchy "checking for a '\n'".

Comment: Thank you Paul. I thought about trying that myself, but I am a student and I have never worked with the stringstream before. I will look into it to see how it works.

Comment: Well, even if you never tried it, at least your first thoughts were on the right track of reading the entire line in first, and then figure out how to handle the string.

Comment: Also, you need to restructure your code to return and fill each line and remove the tests of checking for new lines.  Not knowing how your graph is declared, a concrete answer can't be given.  But I highly suggest you scrap what you're doing now and just read an entire line and parse the data to fill in each "row" of the graph.

Comment: [A small example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51459dd5720d00de)

Comment: Thanks a ton, @PaulMcKenzie! I was able to get it working with the istringstream pretty easily. That was exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help and suggestions.